# Unable to generate Td width value when colspan occur wrong width occur in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a table and colgroup, I am taking table td width form colgroup which are mentioned on top in table.

I need to define width of the td which is specific colgroup. For Ex: for 2nd td in table, width is taken from 2nd colgroup.

It is working fine. but when colspan occur in td it takes only position col width value. I want that when colspan occur it should take all previous col sum in td width.

Input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<table size="s" orient="portrait" tablebodyrowalign="top" width="100">
  <colgroup>
    <col width="19%"/>
    <col width="6%"/>
    <col width="4%"/>
    <col width="9%"/>
    <col width="8%"/>
    <col width="3%"/>
    <col width="16%"/>
    <col width="4%"/>
    <col width="15%"/>
    <col width="2%"/>
    <col width="14%"/>
  </colgroup>
  <thead/>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="5" align="center" valign="middle" fill="000080">
        <para style="TableBodyNoIndent">
          <emph type="Bold">Escrows and Reserves</emph>
          <emph type="Bold">
            <sup>(8)</sup>
          </emph>
        </para>
      </td>
      <td left="single" right="single" align="left" valign="top">
        <para style="TableBodyNoIndent"/>
      </td>
      <td colspan="5" left="single" top="single" right="single" bottom="single"
        align="center" valign="middle" fill="000080">
        <para style="TableBodyNoIndent">
          <emph type="Bold">Financial Information</emph>
          <emph type="Bold">
            <sup>(3)</sup>
          </emph>
        </para>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
       <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
       </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="table">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="tr">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="td">
        <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="style">
            <xsl:variable name="pos">
                <xsl:number/>    
            </xsl:variable>

            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="preceding-sibling::td[@colspan]">
                    <xsl:if test="@fill">
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat('background-color: ','#',@fill, ';')"/>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="@align">
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat('text-align:',@align,';')"/>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat('width:', ancestor::table/colgroup/col[position() = preceding-sibling::td/@colspam +1]/@width, ';')"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:if test="@fill">
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat('background-color: ','#',@fill, ';')"/>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="@align">
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat('text-align:',@align,';')"/>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat('width:', ancestor::table/colgroup/col[position() = $pos]/@width, ';')"/>  
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am try to taking preceding td colspan value + 1 as a current td position but it genrate blank td.  please suggest.

Comment: @Tim C  SIr please help if rowspan comes. how to manage width.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a variable to get the actual position of the `td` taking into account colspans, like so

```
<xsl:variable name="colpos" 
              select="sum(preceding-sibling::td/@colspan) + count(preceding-sibling::td[not(@colspan)]) + 1" />
```

Or as you are using XSLT 2.0, you could write the expression like so...

```
<xsl:variable name="colpos" 
              select="sum(for $td in preceding-sibling::td return (if ($td/@colspan) then $td/@colspan else 1)) + 1" />
```

Or this...

```
<xsl:variable name="colpos" 
              select="sum(preceding-sibling::td/(if (@colspan) then number(@colspan) else 1)) + 1" />
```

So, sum up the colspans where they exist, and count the ones without (which effectively have a colspan of 1).

You then need to get the number of cols in the colgroup to sum up, like so

```
<xsl:variable name="colspan" 
              select="if (@colspan) then number(@colspan) else 1" />
```

Then to get the width of the `td` you can do this

```
 <xsl:value-of 
      select="concat('width:', 
                sum(ancestor::table/colgroup/col[position() ge $colpos and position() lt $colpos + $colspan]/number(replace(@width, '%', ''))), 
                '%;')"/>
```

Try this template

```
<xsl:template match="td">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:attribute name="style">
      <xsl:if test="@fill">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('background-color: ','#',@fill, ';')"/>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="@align">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('text-align:',@align,';')"/>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:variable name="colpos" select="sum(preceding-sibling::td/@colspan) + count(preceding-sibling::td[not(@colspan)]) + 1" />
      <xsl:variable name="colspan" select="if (@colspan) then number(@colspan) else 1" />
      <xsl:value-of select="concat('width:', sum(ancestor::table/colgroup/col[position() ge $colpos and position() lt $colpos + $colspan]/number(replace(@width, '%', ''))), '%;')"/>  
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and suggestion @Tim C. This would give me the width which is mentioned in specif colgroup but I'm expecting sum of width colgroups which are inside this "td". Say Ex: If my 3rd "td" has colspan=3 then, it means 3,4,5 th columns are merged - in this case i should get width of 3 colgroups i.e,3rd,4th & 5th Colgroup's width total as width for "td"

Comment: My apologies. I misunderstood the requirement. I have now updated my answer to hopefully give you the result you require.

Comment: Thanks Tim C for your suggestion. When colspan comes in first td of a tr  then it is not working please suggest

Comment: I tested it at http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFDb2C7 and it seems to work OK for me.

Comment: But it is not get on oxyzen editor  When colspan comes in first td of a tr then it is not working please suggest.

Comment: I am not sure, but can you be precise as to what is "not working"? Are you getting an error, or just the incorrect width value? Are you definitely using the same XML as in the question, and the exact XSLT in my answer too? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Tim C actully you are right, It is working fine, I had put one more condition so i was getting output wrong, sorry for that